# Excel - how to use pivot table to transpose glossary

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm very new to excel and I think I need to use a pivot table for this, but not entirely sure how.

If there is a better way to do this, I would love to learn how.

I have:

```
| pages|        |       |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|   
| 1    |test    |mark
| 2    |dog     |   
| 3    |        |
| 4    |mark    |
| 5    |cat     |test
```

I want:

```
| words | pages|
|:----  |------:|
|cat    |5
|dog    |2
|mark   |1,4
|test   |1,5
```

Comment: Have you considered using VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP instead?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a Pivot Table, you'd need to first reshape your data, for example using Power Query.

An alternative would be to use a formula-based set-up:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A2:C6,
    κ,DROP(ζ,,1),
    λ,TAKE(ζ,,1),
    ξ,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(κ,1))),
    HSTACK(ξ,BYROW(ξ,LAMBDA(γ,TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(κ=γ,λ,"")))))))
)
```

Comment: I guess you use functions from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34 they seem to work only in Excel 365 (according to this page). My version is Excel 2016 and it doesn’t handle the functions you use. (Unfortunately, they seem very handy).

Answer (score 0):

PowerQuery can do all the job. First, declare your table as a table (Insert/Table). Be sure to indicate that your table has already column titles.

Then name your table « table ».

Then Data/New Query/From other source/Empty query. In the « advanced editor », copy:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    Unpivoted = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"pages"}, "Attribut", "Words"),
    Grouped = Table.Group(Unpivoted, {"Words"}, {{"Pages", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([pages],each Number.ToText(_)),","), type text}}),
    Sorted = Table.Sort(Grouped,{{"Words", Order.Ascending}})
in
    Sorted
```

This will work if your table has its first column « table » (case sensitive).